# General way of defining a method within another method without specifically mentioning the class?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

[image]

Since I want to be able to override the calculateusage method within a subclass, would I have to use a whole new drive method for the subclass or is there a way in which I wouldn't have to specifically call on the vehicle class calculateusage?

Comment: Are you subclassing the class in which above two methods are present?

Comment: yes, only that calculateusage is overridden and drive stays the same

Comment: Yes then in that case, you dont have rewrite the same method. Just use self.calculateUsage instead.

Comment: Is recommended to use the code snippet (available in the stack overflow edit answers) instead of images.